# How to find total number of tabs and single space characters from a file in java?

Tags: java

I have been trying to find the total number of tabs and single space characters with using the code below. So if i use this

```
if (c[i] == '\t') {
                        ++tabcount;
                    }
```

it gives tabCount = 0, also if i want to get number of single space characters using this

```
if (c[i] == ' ') {
                        ++singlescpacecount;
                 }
```

it gives total number of white spaces in the whole file.

Code for tabCount is

```
public static void TabCount(String filename) throws IOException{
        int tabcount = 0;
        InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));
        try {
            byte[] c = new byte[1024];

            int readChars = 0;
            while ((readChars = is.read(c)) != -1) {
                for (int i = 0; i < readChars; ++i) {
                    if (c[i] == '\t') {
                        ++tabcount;
                    }

                }
            }
            System.out.println("The total number of tabcounts are :" + tabcount);
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you try this `for (int i = 0; i <= readChars; i++) { }`

Comment: @Amani `<=` is wrong and will cause ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException if file is more than 1k in size.

Comment: it does not work. shows tabcount = 0.

Comment: @AbhishekBiswas Are you *sure* there is a tab in the file? Because your code is working fine.

Comment: yeah preety much sure.

Comment: @Andreas how to find single space chars?

Comment: You find space chars exactly like you showed. I copied your code, made sure all lines were tab-indented, then ran the code on it's own .java file, and it counted the tabs correctly.

Comment: I would not iterate the file multiple times. Instead, create a counter for each character you wish to count (if more than a couple, use an object to store), and then in the for loop, check for each one, incrementing the appropriate counter. The current method name and single output suggests the file may be traversed multiple times to find tabs, spaces, etc.

Comment: @Andreas Don't know what to do? Any fix . or any other snippet you would suggest. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @KevinO Can you provide a snippet code ? Thank you.

Comment: Please use a small t in the method name tabCount. On my computer I had your method print `The total number of tabcounts are :5`. Which was the expected output from the input file I gave it. So it is working correctly.

Comment: Can't suggest anything, since your code is working as it is. If it says that file has `0` tabs, then file has `0` tabs, and you're not reading the file you think you are, or the file does not contain what you think it does. Try creating the text file with nothing but 2 tab characters.

Comment: @Andreas Still nothing. Can you provide your file showhow.

Comment: It sounds like your editor saves tabs *as* spaces.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch  I am using IntellJ Idea version 15.0.6

Comment: Make sure you have [IntelliJ configured correctly](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/changing-indentation.html?origin=old_help#3).

Comment: Almost all IDEs have the ability to convert tabs to spaces upon save.

Comment: @KevinO So I did change the  Edit | Convert Indents  I chose To Tabs . it didn't work.

Comment: Create a file in Notepad with tabs. Use that file as the input file. The code words as noted by @Andreas, and as demonstrated in the answer below. Your input file is not what you expect.

Comment: @KevinO it has worked perfectly. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Andreas thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

At least part of the issue must be that the OP's input file does not contain tabs as expected. As noted by @Andreas, the basic code structure *does* count tabs. However, I had suggested ensuring the file is not iterated multiple times for counting various characters. Here is one implementation on how to do that. It is not optimal, but suggestive.

```
/**
 * A class to accumulate results
 */
static class Results
{
    private int tabs = 0;
    private int spaces = 0;

    public void incTabCount()
    {
        ++tabs;
    }

    public void incSpaceCount()
    {
        ++spaces;
    }

    public int getTabCount()
    {
        return tabs;
    }

    public int getSpaceCount()
    {
        return spaces;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("tabs: ");
        sb.append(tabs);
        sb.append("\nspaces: ");
        sb.append(spaces);

        return sb.toString();
    }
}


/**
 * Iterate the file once, checking for all desired characters,
 * and store in the Results object
 */
public static Results countInFile(String filename) throws IOException
{
    // create results
    Results res = new Results();

    InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));
    try {
        byte[] c = new byte[1024];

        int readChars = 0;
        while ((readChars = is.read(c)) != -1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < readChars; ++i) {
                // see if we have a tab
                if (c[i] == '\t') {
                    res.incTabCount();
                }

                // see if we have a space
                if (c[i] == ' ') {
                    res.incSpaceCount();
                }

            }
        }
    } finally {
        is.close();
    }        

    return res;
}


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Results res;
    try {
        res = countInFile("f:/tmp/test.txt");
        System.out.println(res);            
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Input file (the tab is after the word "has" in the first line):

> This line has\ta tab.
>   And there are 7 spaces?

Based upon an input file, the results are as expected:

> tabs: 1
>   spaces: 7

**Edit:** as an aside, there is a modification that would be ultimately more testable. If one were to separate the File handling from the counting in an input stream, then one could more easily feed a *known* input to the system. For example, modifying the above slightly:

```
/**
 * Counts in a stream the number of tabs and spaces, and returns
 * the Results
 */
private static Results countInStream(InputStream is) throws IOException
{
    // create results
    Results res = new Results();
    try {
        byte[] c = new byte[1024];

        int readChars = 0;
        while ((readChars = is.read(c)) != -1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < readChars; ++i) {
                // see if we have a tab
                if (c[i] == '\t') {
                    res.incTabCount();
                }

                // see if we have a space
                if (c[i] == ' ') {
                    res.incSpaceCount();
                }

            }
        }
    } 
    finally {
    }        

    return res;
}
```

This method may have a `String` passed to it:

```
String s = "This\thas\ttabs.\nAs well as spaces";
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(s.getBytes("UTF8"));
res = countInStream(is);
System.out.println(res);
```

Since it is now much easier to test the main logic, one can clearly see the base counting operates as expected. The `countInFile` method suggest above may be modified to open the InputStream from the file, and then call the `countInStream()`. Such an approach would reduce the debate about whether the *logic* of the method is at issue, or the *contents sent to the method*.

Comment: Thank you  for your precious time. The main problem for me was The editor itself.